# Mariadb sql file to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am using 5.3.0-MariaDB-beta and I will change my dedicate.New server has mysql and I can not import Mariadb sql file to mysql.

How can i import/convert sql file to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be a non-issue if you are going to MySQL 5.3. Just copy over your data files. More here: http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1' at line 18  and line 18 is   `is_register` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

Comment: That sort of message often indicates an error on line 17. Also, how does this relate to your original question?

Comment: because he run the query of mariadb to mysql and got an error, so he's thinking if it's compatible.

Comment: I'm getting error codes trying to import the .sql file from Maria DB 10 into MySQL 8.x. Doesn't matter if using PHPMyAdmin or the MySQL command line. Figuring I'm just going to have to export the tables one at a time and import flat files. Luckily, it's just for a home DB (in my case), but this is annoying nonetheless.