# Importing database to 000webhost and receiving the following error: #1064

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

Error:  - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@', 1) LIMIT 1' at line 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606447/mariadb-sql-file-to-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.When you are importing whole DB then its quite difficult to find the error.

> Check Your 'Option' Column. Problem Could Be In Dumping The Data There.

But I solved it in my way, I didn't import whole DB, I uploaded in pieces.Now what you have to do is

-Import Each Column Manually. 
-Then Dump It Manually

There You Go.